# Clojure Iterate through JSON and update individual keys in map

Tags: json, clojure

I'm new to Clojure, after trying multiple methods I'm completely stuck. I know how to achieve this in any other imperative languages, but not in Clojure.

I have a JSON file https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json containing meteor fall data, each fall includes a mass and year.

I'm trying to find which year had the greatest collective total mass of falls.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(def jsondata
(json/read-str (slurp "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json") :key-fn keyword))

;Get the unique years
(def years (distinct (map :year jsondata)))
;Create map of unique years with a number to hold the total mass
(def yearcount (zipmap years (repeat (count years) 0)))
```

My idea was to use a for function to iterate through the jsondata, and update the yearcount map with the corresponding key (year in the fall object) with the mass of the object (increment it by, as in += in C)

I tried this although I knew it probably wouldn't work:

```
(for [x jsondata]
    (update yearcount (get x :year) (+ (get yearcount (get x :year)) (Integer/parseInt (get x :mass)))))
```

The idea of course being that the yearcount map would hold the totals for each year, on which I could then use frequencies, sort-by, and last to get the year with the highest mass.

Also defined this function to update values in a map with a function, although Im not sure if I could actually use this:

```
(defn map-kv [m f]
  (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (f %3)) {} m))
```

I've tried a few different methods, had lots of issues and just can't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: sorry, I misunderstood the question. I think this will work for you:

```
(->> (group-by :year jsondata)
     (reduce-kv (fn [acc year recs]
                  (let [sum-mass (->> (keep :mass recs)
                                      (map #(Double/parseDouble %))
                                      (reduce +))]
                    (assoc acc year sum-mass)))
                {})
     (sort-by second)
     (last))
=> ["1947-01-01T00:00:00.000" 2.303023E7]
```

The reduce function here is starting out with an initial empty map, and its input will be the output of `group-by` which is a map from years to their corresponding records.

For each step of reduce, the reducing function is receiving the `acc` map we're *building up*, the current `year` key, and the corresponding collection of `recs` for that year. Then we get all the `:mass` values from `recs` (using `keep` instead of `map` because not all `recs` have a mass value apparently). Then we map over that with `Double/parseDouble` to parse the mass strings into numbers. Then we `reduce` over that to *sum* all the masses for all the `recs`. Finally we `assoc` the `year` key to `acc` with the `sum-mass`. This outputs a map from years to their mass sums.

Then we can sort those map key/value pairs by their value (`second` returns the value), then we take the last item with the highest value.

Comment: Ah thanks, however running this with leiningen I keep getting this error ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core/reduce-kv  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

Comment: Not sure what the issue might be. I'm using Leiningen REPL too. The only code I'm using is your `(def jsondata ...)` and then the example in my answer. Maybe try restarting your REPL, or copy/pasting the example again?

Comment: @TaylorWood I'm going to guess that it's a ParInfer issue. If the indentation changes on the paste, ParInfer will cause problems.

Comment: Brilliant, restarted the REPL and now it works for some reason. Thanks a lot mate, especially for the explanation, this is exactly what I was looking for. Need to read up some more on the thread-last macro, but this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate version just to show an approach with a slightly different style. Especially if you're new to clojure it may be easier to see the stepwise thinking that led to the solution.

The tricky part might be the `for` statement, which is another nice way to build up a new collection by (in this case) applying functions to each key and value in an existing map.

```
(defn max-meteor-year [f]
  (let [rdr (io/reader f)
        all-data (json/read rdr :key-fn keyword)
        clean-data (filter #(and (:year %) (:mass %)) all-data)
        grouped-data (group-by #(:year %) clean-data)
        reduced-data
        (for [[k v] grouped-data]
          [(subs k 0 4) (reduce + (map #(Double/parseDouble (:mass %)) v))])]
    (apply max-key second reduced-data)))

clj.meteor> (max-meteor-year "meteor.json")
["1947" 2.303023E7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I think you'll like it because its parts are decoupled and are not joined into a single treading macro. So you may change and test any part of it when something goes wrong.

Fetch the data:

```
(def jsondata
  (json/parse-string
   (slurp "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json")
   true))
```

Pay attention, you may just pass `true` flag that indicates the keys should be keywords rather than strings.

Declare a helper function that takes into account a case when the first argument is missing (is nil):

```
(defn add [a b]
  (+ (or a 0) b))
```

Declare a reduce function that takes a result and an item from a collection of meteor data. It updates the result map with our `add` function we created before. Please note, some items do not have either `mass` or `year` keys; we should check them for existence before operate on them:

```
(defn process [acc {:keys [year mass]}]
  (if (and year mass)
    (update acc year add (Double/parseDouble mass))
    acc))
```

The final step is to run reducing algorithm:

```
(reduce process {} jsondata)
```

The result is:

```
{"1963-01-01T00:00:00.000" 58946.1,
 "1871-01-01T00:00:00.000" 21133.0,
 "1877-01-01T00:00:00.000" 89810.0,
 "1926-01-01T00:00:00.000" 16437.0,
 "1866-01-01T00:00:00.000" 559772.0,
 "1863-01-01T00:00:00.000" 33710.0,
 "1882-01-01T00:00:00.000" 314462.0,
 "1949-01-01T00:00:00.000" 215078.0,
```

I think that such a step-by-step solution is much more clearer and maintainable than a single huge `->>` thread.

Comment: Just as a side note, you can define add as `(def add (fnil + 0))`, a bit more concise way IMO.